# ImportError: cannot import name 'total_ordering' from 'functools' error in Pycharm virtual env

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, virtualenv, python-import

All of a sudden i am getting below error while running my code in Pycharm. Earlier It was working fine. I tried changing the interpretar from virtual en to base interpreter but no resolve

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ubhatia/PycharmProjects/ModerationReport/resources/user_keywords/keyword.py", line 3, in <module>
    from robot.api.deco import library, keyword
  File "/Users/ubhatia/.virtualenvs/ModerationReport/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from robot.rebot import rebot, rebot_cli
  File "/Users/ubhatia/.virtualenvs/ModerationReport/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/rebot.py", line 40, in <module>
    from robot.conf import RebotSettings
  File "/Users/ubhatia/.virtualenvs/ModerationReport/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/conf/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .settings import RobotSettings, RebotSettings
  File "/Users/ubhatia/.virtualenvs/ModerationReport/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/conf/settings.py", line 16, in <module>
    import glob
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/glob.py", line 4, in <module>
    import re
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 127, in <module>
    import functools
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/collections/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from keyword import iskeyword as _iskeyword
  File "/Users/ubhatia/PycharmProjects/ModerationReport/resources/user_keywords/keyword.py", line 3, in <module>
    from robot.api.deco import library, keyword
  File "/Users/ubhatia/.virtualenvs/ModerationReport/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/api/__init__.py", line 71, in <module>
    from robot.model import SuiteVisitor
  File "/Users/ubhatia/.virtualenvs/ModerationReport/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/model/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .body import BaseBody, Body, BodyItem, Branches
  File "/Users/ubhatia/.virtualenvs/ModerationReport/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/model/body.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .itemlist import ItemList
  File "/Users/ubhatia/.virtualenvs/ModerationReport/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robot/model/itemlist.py", line 17, in <module>
    from functools import total_ordering
ImportError: cannot import name 'total_ordering' from 'functools' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/functools.py)
```

This is the piece of code i am running

```
import time
from datetime import date, timedelta
from robot.api.deco import library, keyword
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
import pandas as pd


def get_current_date():
    today = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    return today


def get_yesterday_date():
    today = date.today()
    yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
    return yesterday.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')


def read_excel_and_change_to_list(excel_path):
    return pd.read_excel(excel_path)


print(get_current_date())
```

**Can anyone help me out on how to resolve this issue please?**

Comment: Please check the `robot.api.deco`, with dependencies that the `robot` packages need to be installed first. This may cause since the `functools` was too new or too old version.

Comment: You can try upgrade your `functools` version or downgrade it

Comment: how can we upgrade/downgrade funtools?

Comment: I am not sure if the `functools` could be upgraded/downgraded or not. But if you want to upgrade/downgraded a package `<name>` to a specific version `<version>`, using the following command
`pip install <name>==<version>`
Please note that you need to check which `<version>` the `robot` package needs to.

Comment: You can't upgrade `functools` on its own because it's in the standard library that comes with Python. Do not attempt to mix and match standard library modules from different versions of Python. `total_ordering()` was added in 3.2 which is over 10 years ago. Check PyCharm's setting for the version of Python: ctrl-alt-S, Python interpreter.

Comment: @dungxibo123 I have removed 'from robot.api.deco import library, keyword',
'from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn' and then it is throwing error for pandas

It is giving below error then:

ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: cannot import name 'iskeyword' from 'keyword' (/Users/ubhatia/PycharmProjects/ModerationReport/resources/user_keywords/keyword.py)
pytz: cannot import name 'iskeyword' from 'keyword' (/Users/ubhatia/PycharmProjects/ModerationReport/resources/user_keywords/keyword.py)

by also removing pandas import the code does seem to work

Comment: Seem to be your virtual environment met some big problem, Have you tried to remove the `env` and made new one ?